# Roots of this trigonometric polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, roots

Let $f:[0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{k}a_n \left(1+\cos(x)\right)^n$ for arbitrary $a_n$ with $a_k \neq 0$. My question is: What is the maximum number of zeros that this function can have?

Comment: Replace $\cos x$ by $y$ to get a polynomial in $y$. What is the degree? How many zeros can that polynomial have? How many values in $[0,2\pi)$ correspond to each zero $y_m$?

Comment: $k$ zeros, so at most $2k$ zeros due to periodicity?

Comment: That is correct.